# Error compilation oracle loadjava innerclass

Tags: oracle, inner-classes, loadjava

I want to load some Java classes in oracle db 12c. When I compile locally all .java and load the resulting classes, there isn't any problem. But if I want to use the Oracle server-side compiler instead, i.e. load the .java source files, there are weird errors.
I have lots of java class. Look at this :

```
PS C:\pdgm\OpenDB\NetcdfLight\src> loadjava -u llamarche/qwerty thredds/catalog/DataFormatType.java ucar/ma2/Array.java
ucar/ma2/ArrayBoolean.java ucar/ma2/ArrayByte.java ucar/ma2/ArrayChar.java ucar/ma2/ArrayDouble.java ucar/ma2/ArrayFloat
.java ucar/ma2/ArrayInt.java ucar/ma2/ArrayLong.java ucar/ma2/ArrayObject.java ucar/ma2/ArrayRagged.java ucar/ma2/ArrayS
calar.java ucar/ma2/ArraySequence.java ucar/ma2/ArraySequenceNested.java ucar/ma2/ArrayShort.java ucar/ma2/ArrayString.j
ava ucar/ma2/ArrayStructure.java ucar/ma2/ArrayStructureBB.java ucar/ma2/ArrayStructureBBpos.java ucar/ma2/ArrayStructur
eComposite.java ucar/ma2/ArrayStructureMA.java ucar/ma2/ArrayStructureW.java ucar/ma2/DataType.java ucar/ma2/ForbiddenCo
nversionException.java ucar/ma2/Index.java ucar/ma2/Index0D.java ucar/ma2/Index1D.java ucar/ma2/Index2D.java ucar/ma2/In
dex3D.java ucar/ma2/Index4D.java ucar/ma2/Index5D.java ucar/ma2/Index6D.java ucar/ma2/Index7D.java ucar/ma2/IndexConstan
t.java ucar/ma2/IndexIterator.java ucar/ma2/InvalidRangeException.java ucar/ma2/IteratorFast.java ucar/ma2/MAMath.java u
car/ma2/MAMatrix.java ucar/ma2/MAVector.java ucar/ma2/Range.java ucar/ma2/Section.java ucar/ma2/SequenceIterator.java uc
ar/ma2/StructureData.java ucar/ma2/StructureDataA.java ucar/ma2/StructureDataComposite.java ucar/ma2/StructureDataFactor
y.java ucar/ma2/StructureDataIterator.java ucar/ma2/StructureDataIteratorLimited.java ucar/ma2/StructureDataScalar.java
ucar/ma2/StructureDataW.java ucar/ma2/StructureMembers.java ucar/nc2/Attribute.java ucar/nc2/CDMNode.java ucar/nc2/CDMSo
rt.java ucar/nc2/Dimension.java ucar/nc2/EnumTypedef.java ucar/nc2/Group.java ucar/nc2/NetcdfFile.java ucar/nc2/ParsedSe
ctionSpec.java ucar/nc2/ProxyReader.java ucar/nc2/SectionReader.java ucar/nc2/Sequence.java ucar/nc2/SliceReader.java uc
ar/nc2/Structure.java ucar/nc2/Variable.java ucar/nc2/VariableIF.java ucar/nc2/VariableSimpleIF.java ucar/nc2/constants/
AxisType.java ucar/nc2/constants/CDM.java ucar/nc2/constants/CF.java ucar/nc2/constants/FeatureType.java ucar/nc2/consta
nts/_Coordinate.java ucar/nc2/ft/grid/IsMissingEvaluator.java ucar/nc2/iosp/AbstractIOServiceProvider.java ucar/nc2/iosp
/BitReader.java ucar/nc2/iosp/IOServiceProvider.java ucar/nc2/iosp/IOServiceProviderWriter.java ucar/nc2/iosp/IndexChunk
er.java ucar/nc2/iosp/IndexChunkerTiled.java ucar/nc2/iosp/IndexLong.java ucar/nc2/iosp/IospHelper.java ucar/nc2/iosp/La
yout.java ucar/nc2/iosp/LayoutBB.java ucar/nc2/iosp/LayoutBBTiled.java ucar/nc2/iosp/LayoutRegular.java ucar/nc2/iosp/La
youtRegularSegmented.java ucar/nc2/iosp/LayoutSegmented.java ucar/nc2/iosp/LayoutTiled.java ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf4/HdfEos.ja
va ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/BTree2.java ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/DataBTree.java ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/FractalHeap.java ucar/nc2/iosp/hd
f5/H5diag.java ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/H5header.java ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/H5iosp.java ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/H5tiledLayout.java uca
r/nc2/iosp/hdf5/H5tiledLayoutBB.java ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/MemTracker.java ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/Tiling.java ucar/nc2/iosp/net
cdf3/N3iosp.java ucar/nc2/iosp/netcdf4/Nc4.java ucar/nc2/util/CancelTask.java ucar/nc2/util/EscapeStrings.java ucar/nc2/
util/IO.java ucar/nc2/util/Indent.java ucar/nc2/util/Misc.java ucar/nc2/util/UnsynchronizedBufferedWriter.java ucar/nc2/
util/rc/RC.java ucar/unidata/io/KMPMatch.java ucar/unidata/io/PositioningDataInputStream.java ucar/unidata/io/RandomAcce
ssFile.java ucar/unidata/io/blob/BlobRandomAccessFile.java ucar/unidata/util/Format.java ucar/unidata/util/GaussianLatit
udes.java ucar/unidata/util/Parameter.java ucar/unidata/util/SpecialMathFunction.java ucar/unidata/util/StringUtil2.java
 ucar/unidata/util/Urlencoded.java -resolve
errors   : source ucar/ma2/Array
    ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble:64: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayDoubl
e$1
                return new ArrayDouble.D0(index, storage);
                                                 ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayBoolean
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayByte
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayChar
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayDouble
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayFloat
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayInt
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayLong
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayObject
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayRagged
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
    ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble:64: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayDoubl
e$1
                return new ArrayDouble.D0(index, storage);
                                                 ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayScalar
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
    ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble:64: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayDoubl
e$1
                return new ArrayDouble.D0(index, storage);
                                                 ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArraySequence
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArraySequenceNested
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
    ucar.ma2.ArrayObject:62: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayObject$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayObjec
t$1
                return new ArrayObject.D0(classType, index, storage);
                                                            ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayShort
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayString
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayStructure
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayStructureBB
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayStructureBBpos
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
    ucar.ma2.ArrayObject:62: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayObject$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayObjec
t$1
                return new ArrayObject.D0(classType, index, storage);
                                                            ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayStructureComposite
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
    ucar.ma2.ArrayObject:62: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayObject$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayObjec
t$1
                return new ArrayObject.D0(classType, index, storage);
                                                            ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayStructureMA
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
    ucar.nc2.CDMNode:292: error while writing <anonymous ucar.nc2.CDMNode$1>: destination for ucar.nc2.CDMNode$1
                break;
                ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ArrayStructureW
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/DataType
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/ForbiddenConversionException
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/Index
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/Index0D
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/Index1D
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/Index2D
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/Index3D
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/Index4D
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/Index5D
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/Index6D
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/Index7D
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/IndexConstant
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/IndexIterator
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/InvalidRangeException
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/IteratorFast
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/MAMath
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/MAMatrix
    ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble:64: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayDoubl
e$1
                return new ArrayDouble.D0(index, storage);
                                                 ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/ma2/MAVector
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/Range
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/Section
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/SequenceIterator
    ucar.ma2.ArrayObject:62: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayObject$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayObjec
t$1
                return new ArrayObject.D0(classType, index, storage);
                                                            ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/ma2/StructureData
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/StructureDataA
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/StructureDataComposite
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
    ucar.ma2.ArrayObject:62: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayObject$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayObjec
t$1
                return new ArrayObject.D0(classType, index, storage);
                                                            ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/ma2/StructureDataFactory
    ucar.ma2.ArrayObject:62: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayObject$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayObjec
t$1
                return new ArrayObject.D0(classType, index, storage);
                                                            ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/ma2/StructureDataIterator
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/StructureDataIteratorLimited
    ucar.ma2.ArrayObject:62: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayObject$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayObjec
t$1
                return new ArrayObject.D0(classType, index, storage);
                                                            ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/ma2/StructureDataScalar
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
    ucar.ma2.ArrayObject:62: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayObject$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayObjec
t$1
                return new ArrayObject.D0(classType, index, storage);
                                                            ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/ma2/StructureDataW
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/ma2/StructureMembers
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/Attribute
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/CDMNode
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/CDMSort
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/Dimension
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/EnumTypedef
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/Group
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/NetcdfFile
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/ParsedSectionSpec
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/ProxyReader
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/SectionReader
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/Sequence
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/SliceReader
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/Structure
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/Variable
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/VariableIF
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/VariableSimpleIF
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/constants/CDM
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/constants/CF
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/constants/FeatureType
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/ft/grid/IsMissingEvaluator
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/AbstractIOServiceProvider
    ucar.nc2.CDMNode:292: error while writing <anonymous ucar.nc2.CDMNode$1>: destination for ucar.nc2.CDMNode$1
                break;
                ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/IOServiceProvider
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/IOServiceProviderWriter
    ucar.nc2.CDMNode:292: error while writing <anonymous ucar.nc2.CDMNode$1>: destination for ucar.nc2.CDMNode$1
                break;
                ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/IndexChunker
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
    ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble:64: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayDoubl
e$1
                return new ArrayDouble.D0(index, storage);
                                                 ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/IndexChunkerTiled
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
    ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble:64: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayDoubl
e$1
                return new ArrayDouble.D0(index, storage);
                                                 ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/IndexLong
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/IospHelper
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/Layout
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/LayoutBB
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/LayoutBBTiled
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
    ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble:64: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayDoubl
e$1
                return new ArrayDouble.D0(index, storage);
                                                 ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/LayoutRegular
    ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble:64: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayDoubl
e$1
                return new ArrayDouble.D0(index, storage);
                                                 ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/LayoutRegularSegmented
    ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble:64: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayDoubl
e$1
                return new ArrayDouble.D0(index, storage);
                                                 ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/LayoutSegmented
    ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble:64: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayDoubl
e$1
                return new ArrayDouble.D0(index, storage);
                                                 ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/LayoutTiled
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
    ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble:64: error while writing <anonymous ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble$1>: destination for ucar.ma2.ArrayDoubl
e$1
                return new ArrayDouble.D0(index, storage);
                                                 ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/BTree2
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
    ucar.nc2.CDMNode:292: error while writing <anonymous ucar.nc2.CDMNode$1>: destination for ucar.nc2.CDMNode$1
                break;
                ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/DataBTree
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/FractalHeap
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/H5diag
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
    ucar.nc2.CDMNode:292: error while writing <anonymous ucar.nc2.CDMNode$1>: destination for ucar.nc2.CDMNode$1
                break;
                ^
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/H5header
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/H5iosp
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/H5tiledLayout
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/H5tiledLayoutBB
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/MemTracker
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf5/Tiling
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/netcdf3/N3iosp
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/iosp/netcdf4/Nc4
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/util/CancelTask
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/util/EscapeStrings
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/util/IO
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/util/Indent
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/util/Misc
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/util/UnsynchronizedBufferedWriter
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/nc2/util/rc/RC
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/unidata/io/PositioningDataInputStream
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/unidata/io/blob/BlobRandomAccessFile
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/unidata/util/Format
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/unidata/util/Parameter
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/unidata/util/SpecialMathFunction
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
errors   : source ucar/unidata/util/StringUtil2
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
The following operations failed
    source ucar/ma2/Array: resolution
    [...]
    source ucar/unidata/util/StringUtil2: resolution
exiting  : Failures occurred during processing
```

Here is the line 64 of ArrayDouble :

```
static ArrayDouble factory(Index index) {
    return ArrayDouble.factory(index, null);
}


static ArrayDouble factory(Index index, double[] storage) {
    if(index.getRank() == 0)
        return new ArrayDouble.D0(index, storage);
    else if(index.getRank() == 1)
        return new ArrayDouble.D1(index, storage);
    else if(index.getRank() == 2)
        return new ArrayDouble.D2(index, storage);
    else if(index.getRank() == 3)
        return new ArrayDouble.D3(index, storage);
    else if(index.getRank() == 4)
        return new ArrayDouble.D4(index, storage);
    else if(index.getRank() == 5)
        return new ArrayDouble.D5(index, storage);
    else if(index.getRank() == 6)
        return new ArrayDouble.D6(index, storage);
    else if(index.getRank() == 7)
        return new ArrayDouble.D7(index, storage);
    else
        return new ArrayDouble(index, storage);

}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Try loading java classes using -genmissing, -fileoutput and -resolve options which would provide more information regarding errors and would help to compile classes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayDouble had inner-classes (ArrayDouble.D0 - ArrayDouble.D7) which extends ArrayDouble. So I think there is a loop than the compiler doesn't like. I have moved inner-classes to outer classes and it works now.